# How do I mention a user in an array

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

(Using Python 3.9)

So I'm making a bot called TomBot that is known as the loveable android for the series that this bot is made around. One of the items it will respond to is a compliment, and I want it to pick randomly from an array of responses for its actual response.

This all is fine, except I only want one (so far) of the responses inside the array to actually mention the user that posted the item. I thought I could simply move ctx.message.author.mention from client.say(random.choice(responses) + ", " + ctx.message.author.mention) into the array itself, separated from the custom strings. However I am getting a Syntax error when I do so. What am I missing?

```
@client.command(name='Tom is the best!', 
    description="Responds to compliments", 
    pass_context=True)
async def compliment():
    compliment_responses = [
        "Gee, thanks!!"
        "Aww, you're pretty neat, too, " ctx.message.author.mention, "!"
    ]
    await client.say(random.choice(compliment_responses))
```

When executing this code, the below is the response:

```
File "E:\git\tombot\bot-v0.0.1.py", line 32
  "Aww, you're pretty neat, too, " ctx.message.author.mention, "!"
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are improperly "embedding" a variable into a string. There are many variations of doing it. Here are a few:

```py
text = f'Your text is here. {your_variable_here}, and some more text here.'
```

You can also use the `.format()` method to add a variable to the middle of a string:

```py
text = 'Your text is here. {}, and some more text here'.format(your_variable_here)
```

The example just above will replace the `{}` with whatever variable is specified in the `.format()` method.

With both methods, you can have multiple variables in one string. In your case, you have two options to change to what you would like:

```py
compliment_responses = [
    "Gee, thanks!!",
    "Aww, you're pretty neat, too, {ctx.message.author.mention}!"
]
```

Or you can use the `.format()` method with your string:

```py
compliment_responses = [
    "Gee, thanks!!",
    "Aww, you're pretty neat, too, {}!".format(ctx.message.author.mention)
]
```

Both methods should work.

Answer (score 0):

You're ending a string and trying to drop a variable in the middle, that won't work since it's inavlid syntax. What you want can be achieved with f strings like so:

```
f"have text here {var_here} more text over here"
```

Whatever you put inside the curly braces will be evaluated and its return value insderted in the string. Be sure to put an f at the start of the string to signal it's an f string.